# Error "expression must have integral or enum type" in thats code:

Tags: cuda

Error "expression must have integral or enum type" in thats code:

```
__global__ void VectorKernel(float *a, float *b, float *c, int n)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    float y = 0, z = 0;

if (i < n)

    y = (b-a) / n;

    for (float j = y; j <= n ; j++) {
        z = (((j+y) - j) / 6) * function(j) + 4 * (function((j + (y+j)) / 2)) + function(y+j);

        c = c + z;
    }
}
```

the error happen in "z", in stretch:

```
c = c + z;
```

(i'm beginner in CUDA programming)

Comment: `c` is a **pointer**.  You should not be adding `z`, a `float` quantity, to a pointer.   Perhaps you meant `*c = *c + z;`.  This is a C programming issue, not specific to CUDA.  `b` and `a` are pointers also, so it seems to me that something like `(b-a)` is not really what you want either.

Comment: thank you !
i don't post the part that i move the variables to GPU for precessing.

Comment: In my case, this error was issued when I used 2 angle brackets instead of 3 on CUDA kernel call. i.e.: doing `<<...>>` instead of `<<<...>>>`. I ended up here while googling, so this may help someone.

Answer (score 6):

`c` is a pointer. Pointer arithmetic requires a pointer and an integer type expression.

If you want to to add `z` to the `float` pointed to by `c` you should change the expression to:

```
*c = *c + z;
```

Comment: Or `*c += z;` for compactness.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `c = c + z` and get an error like this, you should suspect your types are mismatched.
`c` is a `float *` and `z` is a `float` which are not assignable.

What you probably want to do is store the result of `*c + z` in the memory location pointed at by `c`, in which case you'd write:
`*c = *c + z`.